# Reinitialize a single Exchange 2010 mailbox?

Tags: exchange-2010, powershell, email-server

I'm running PST import tests on a new Exchange 2010 SP1 server. I'm interested in seeing if there's a quick way to restore the account to default and clear its contents. Kind of a reset or reinitialization of a single account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution in the [Exchange 2010 SP1 documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd298173.aspx) and [this forum post](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/exchange2010/thread/6eee3786-6f59-4555-981d-90a17af9a270).

`Search-Mailbox -Identity username -DeleteContent` works well and deletes the content of the user's mailbox/contacts/etc. It seems to keep folder structure intact, though.

For Exchange 2013, [this need to be done first](http://www.codetwo.com/kb/how-to-delete-a-user-s-mailbox-content/) - (add the "Mailbox Import Export" and "Mailbox Search" roles).

Answer (score 4):

If by account, you mean specifically the mailbox, I would diable the mailbox (removing it also removes the user account), and just add back a new mailbox (not re-connect). I have done that in the past, and just tested it again.

If I did not understand your question fully, what on the account are you trying to get back to the default?